# Можно ли продвигать коммерческие запросы на страницах блога?

Tags: seo

Ситуация следующая...
Продвигаю сайт http://example.com

Из-за дурацкого шаблона, каждая услуга находится на странице записи, то есть записи блога, а не на странице. Сайт работает на WordPress.

Вопрос: на сколько существенно то, что услуги описываются в записях блога а не на страницах? Не будет ли это усложнять продвижение?

Comment: Продвигайте, только не здесь.

Comment: Не понял. Это к чему Вы? Я не должен был сайт указывать?

Comment: Да, в вопросе не должно быть лишней и рекламной информации, не относящейся к делу, а также ссылок на сторонние сайты. Вся необходимая информация и код должны быть в теле вопроса.

Comment: Учту. Спасибо! Но это была не реклама, я подумал что может взгляд на сайт поможет в вопросе.

Вопрос я задал не для того чтоб разместить ссылку. Вопрос актуален. Так что если подскажете что-то - буду признателен

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что не относится к программированию.

Comment: При чем тут программирование, если я разместил вопрос с меткой "seo"???

Comment: @tarik Потому что есть некоторые темы пограничные -- то администрирование (как установить windows, выбрать wi-fi роутер), то seo (где вообще всё зыбко с критериями ответов из-за того, что поисковики не любят афишировать детали своих алгоритмов). Некоторые теги вообще уже под запретом фактически: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/841/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/843#843

Answer (score 1):

Конкретные алгоритмы поисковые системы не очень любят афишировать, поэтому во многом ответы на seo-вопросы являются нечёткими, размытыми.

Так и в вашем случае рекомендация будет чем-то вроде "делайте сайт для людей, а не для роботов -- и тогда у вас будут хорошие показатели в глазах поисковиков". 
А вы кстати в первую очередь именно думаете о том, как будет поисковиками оцениваться сайт.

Попробуйте понять: с точки зрения обычного посетителя есть ли разница, описание вашей услуги сделано на странице блога или на странице сайта? Это собственно и будет ключом к вашему ответу.

С чисто технической точки зрения, для поисковика нет разницы, какую страницу индексировать -- http://site.tld/blog/kuplya-zolota или http://site.tld/kuplya-zolota/ -- это для него несущественно и то, и то просто строка url.

Всё это "при прочих равных". То есть, если у вас шаблон кривой и, допустим, на странице блога автоматически генерит тег тайтл (совсем не так, как вам нужно), а на обычных страницах вы можете проставлять тайтл более гибко. Но ЧПУ -- вещь, которая совершенно спокойно везде включается.

Лично я бы предпочёл оформить отдельной страницей, но это чистой воды вкусовщина. Вполне допускаю, что и размещение в блоге можно вылизать до состояния "конфетки", было бы желание и усердие.

По факту, больше влияния оказывают в настоящее время поведенческие факторы -- сколько времени пользователь разглядывал страницу (насколько интересна услуга), какое количество отказов и т.п.

Так что уделяйте основное внимание именно вещам, интересным пользователю, а не поисковику.

Comment: Для пользователя видна разница только в хлебных крошках. Если сделать все через страницы, то над текстом удобно (как по мне) видно где ты находишься, по тому, что есть услуги, есть "подуслуги" (разновидности).

По идеи, через страницы делать лучше еще и по тому, что так можно сделать структуру, и она отобразится в быстрых ссылках со временем. Но просто было интересно мнение, все таки есть ли разница на страницах блога или страницах сайта находятся запросы. 

Спасибо за ответ!